# Geometric Series - partial sum (processing efficiency)

Tags: node.js, math, server, processing-efficiency

so here is my situation.  I have to solve a math problem on server end and could expect tens of thousands of requests a second so I'm trying to find the most efficient path to solving the problem.

Client will submit some number, let's call it A, and I need to determine base of the exponent in a geometric series (see below) where the result will be as close to A as possible without exceeding it.

The problem is that in the real-world, each value of the geometric series is rounded, so standard math can't apply.

round(x^1)+round(x^2)+round(x^3).

I can use the partial sum of geometric series equation to find some rough upper and lower limits using:

((x)^(n+1)-1)/((x)-1)

So say x=2 is a lower limit and x=2.03 is an upper limit... and the value i'm solving for is x=2.02392372838123.

So far the only solution i found was to use a recursive function to go through decimals individually testing until I find the number, but the load on the server is too high at the volume of requests I expect.  (I am using node.js).

Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions on a more efficient way to solve this?  Again the only reason I can't solve this with math alone (to the best of my skill) is because of the real-world rounding of numbers in the sum.

Thanks.

Comment: Function `F(x) = round(x^1)+round(x^2)+round(x^3) + ....round(x^n)` 
is staircase, and has no reverse function in traditional sense - for every F(x) value there exists **a range** of x values.

Comment: Can you clarify what is given and what you want to find? Also, what is the exact function? Is it an infinite series or only part of it? If `x` is greater than one, the infinite series will diverge.